# Boost log marcro explaination

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I followed the boost log tutorial here
http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html

I tries to compile and run this sample

```
//[ example_tutorial_trivial
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main(int, char*[])
{
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

return 0;
}
```

It can not compile . Errors return as http://pastebin.com/DcLdWGke

Then i edit my code as follow :

```
#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK
//[ example_tutorial_trivial
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main(int, char*[])
{
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

return 0;
}
```

Now it complied and worked well .I read about this marcro on the boost site :

> If defined in user code, the library will assume the binary is built
>   as a dynamically loaded library ("dll" or "so"). Otherwise it is
>   assumed that the library is built in static mode. This macro must be
>   either defined or not defined for all translation units of user
>   application that uses logging. This macro can help with auto-linking
>   on platforms that support it.

**So my question is : why i need #define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK to compiled ?**

Answer (score 0):

`#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK`

will forces all libraries that have separate source of their own, to be linked as dll's instead of static libraries.

Ref: `\boost_1_xx_0\boost\config\user.hpp` for details

To configure boost, use the user config header `<boost/config/user.hpp>`

Comment: So that means log library can not be loaded as static libraries . And i have to load it as dynamic library ?

Comment: IMHO, the static boost libraries may not have been available when trying to compile the example. (sorry, couldn't leave this unanswered)